# BackgroundImage size is 0 in StackPane, it shouldn't be

Tags: image, javafx, background

I'm trying to create a matrix (GridPane) as rootPane for the Scene, filled with StackPanes that are filled with BackgroundImages. These Images aren't displayed (even as Node ( = ImageView)).

I've tried some workarounds, but still these pictures aren't displayed. I'd identified that the problem SEEMS TO be that the height and width of them are 0, why ever.

As I mentioned, I tried to give these .png's as Node to the StackPane, but their size stay 0 in each direction.

Here's my code:

```java
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        StackPane spForMatrix[] = new StackPane[100];
        GridPane matrix = new GridPane();
        matrix.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/matrixReadIn.txt")));
        sc.useDelimiter(",");

        String datahold = null;
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        try {
            while ((datahold = sc.next()) != null)
            {
                if (j == 10)
                {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }

                Image im = getDecisionForBackground(datahold);

                spForMatrix[k] = new StackPane();
                spForMatrix[k].setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(im, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(BackgroundSize.AUTO,
                        BackgroundSize.AUTO, false, false, true, true))));
                spForMatrix[k].getChildren().add(new Label(datahold));
                matrix.add(spForMatrix[k], j, i);
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException nsee)
        {
            System.out.println("closed with nsee error");
            sc.close();
        }

        sc.close();

        Scene primaryScene = new Scene(matrix);
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Image getDecisionForBackground(String datahold) throws URISyntaxException
    {
        int metaBinder = Integer.parseInt(datahold);

        if (metaBinder == 0)
            return new Image("file:brown.png", 64, 64, false, false);
        else if (metaBinder == 1)
            return new Image("file:blue.png", 64, 64, false, false);
        else
            return new Image("file:green.png", 64, 64, false, false);
    }
```

I've created the while cause it was simpler as I tested it, perhaps I'll change it for further tests.

The StackPane[] is more or less for fun.

The if-else Structure in the `getDecisionForBackground()` were a switch-case once; I think I change it if my problem is solved.

Note that the information where which picture should be inserted will be extracted from a .txt, filled with numbers.

I'm out of ideas where the problem comes from, and what I should (or can) do that the pictures will be displayed (unless I have to work with CSS, but I don't believe it).

It would be nice if someone can tell me why the scaling is zero, and what I have to do to change it.

Edit: Thank to the cheerful help of fabian (comment section) I've found the problem; I just forgot to add an FileInputStream for the .png's.

Can be closed. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the images are loaded successfully? Add a listener to the `error` property of the `Image`s and check, if the property ever becomes true.

Comment: I'd never added a Listener, so I have to check out how it is working. But if I call image.isError() it give's back true, so I think I've done something very incorrect or I've forgot something necessary :/

Comment: The `exception` property should provide you with additional information. Just print the stacktrace, if there is an exception. Not sure which one of the properties is updated first though (maybe I should have recommended adding a listener to this property instead in the first place). My assumption: the urls are wrong. For read-only data that the application needs I recommend using resources instead btw...

Comment: Yeah, you've got right. It is a FileNotFoundException. Okay, I'll try it with those then.